# How can I do a tell a button in tkinter to do a function if Hold for more than 1sec?

Tags: button, tkinter

I wanted to create a button which

If pressed: 
    Does something. 
If Hold for more than 2sec: 
    Do something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code,

```
from tkinter import*
import time
win=Tk()
start=0
mous=False
button=Button(win,text="hold me for 2 sec")
button.pack()
def pressed(e):
    global start
    start=time.time()
def released(e):
    global start
    stop=time.time()
    x=int(stop-start)
    if x>=2:
        print("hai")

button.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",pressed)
button.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",released)
win.mainloop()
```